# Simple batch file to close application not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I have a very simple batch file that needs work.

I'm using this solution (https://github.com/mikew/xarcade-xinput) which works perfect in my situation... however it will open a web browser and command console when executed. The browser opens to show additional control options, but the default works and isn't essentially needed (the console needs to stay open or the program exits).

I'm running an arcade front end and actually need the browser and console to minimize upon opening or else it will interfere with some games.

The basic batch file I made below to open the xarcade-xinput.exe file works to open the program. However, I'm not clear on how to use "start /min" in this case to minimize (or if another option exists).

```
@echo off 
cd C:\Users\VORTEX\Desktop\xarcade-xinput
"XArcade XInput.exe"
```

Also, there is an exit batch file I made that will close the console (which then kills the program). However, the browser will not close.

```
taskkill /IM cmd.exe
taskkill /IM chrome.exe
```

I'm attempting to work this out but can't seem to get a working solution. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: `start "" /MIN "XArcade XInput.exe"`

Comment: `taskkill /t /f` See `taskkill /?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If chrome is not closing, try forcing it to close and all processes started by it with `/t` and `/f` switches of `taskkill`. See `taskkill /?`

If you did look at `start /?`, check it again,

> ```
> MIN         Start window minimized.
> ```

For what you have now, this is what you want:

```batch-file
@ECHO Off
cd "C:\Users\VORTEX\Desktop\xarcade-xinput"
start /MIN "XArcade XInput.exe"
```

And for your "exit batch file" (I don't know the rest of your code but this seems entirely unnecessary. )

```batch-file
@ECHO Off
taskkill /t /f /im chrome.exe
taskkill /t /f /im cmd.exe
```